# SPUtility.SendEmail() always returns false

Tags: c#, email, sharepoint-2010, smtp

I have one application which will create task form for each level based on the prior level approval. While creating each tasks I have to send the email to the users who all are involved in the task. For this I am using SPUtility.SendEmail() method. But unfortunately, it didn't work so far. The debugger successfully passed through the SendEmail method without any exception. but the value will always false. The SMTP server is working for the application other than the SP Applications. My code is shown below.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(SiteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    headers = new StringDictionary();
                    headers.Add("to", To);
                    headers.Add("from", From);
                    headers.Add("cc", CC);
                    headers.Add("bcc", BCC);
                    if (Priority.Equals("High"))
                    {
                        headers.Add("X-Priority", "1 (Highest)");
                        headers.Add("X-MSMail-Priority", "High");
                        headers.Add("Importance", "High");
                    }
                    headers.Add("subject", Subject);
                    headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");
                    Status = SPUtility.SendEmail(spWeb, true, true, To, Subject, Body);
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. All Suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set up the outgoing email SMTP in sharepoint admin?

Comment: @user3373870: yes. I did..

Comment: see what does this give you when you debug your code
Of course you have to change (web); to your website
`var IsEmailServerSet = SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet(web);`

Comment: @user3373870 : IsEmailServerSet getting true.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few minutes ago.
You might have a problem with smtp server RELAY.

Try this:

1. Open IIS 6.
2. *Go To SMTP Virtual Server* (Open properties)
3. Tab ***General***: Select IP adddress of the server in the dropdown
4. Tab ***Access***:

   4.1 In *Access Control* ensure anonymous access is checked

   4.2 In *Relay Restrictions* add IP: 127.0.0.1 and IP address of the server
5. Tab **Delivery**: Go to button "Outbound Connections" and set port = 587

that´s all.
I hope helpfull

Comment: Right! Surprisingly "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" is no use. As soon as I started "Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager" and clicked "local computer" I saw that [SMTP Virtual Server #1] was in "stopped" status! Probably since I restarted IIS last time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using the wrong method signature. You're going to the trouble of setting up headers as a StringDictionary, but then you're using the overload of `SPUtility.SendEmail()` that doesn't use those headers.
Try this instead:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(SiteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    headers = new StringDictionary();
                    headers.Add("to", To);
                    headers.Add("from", From);
                    headers.Add("cc", CC);
                    headers.Add("bcc", BCC);
                    if (Priority.Equals("High"))
                    {
                        headers.Add("X-Priority", "1 (Highest)");
                        headers.Add("X-MSMail-Priority", "High");
                        headers.Add("Importance", "High");
                    }
                    headers.Add("subject", Subject);
                    headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");
                    Status = SPUtility.SendEmail(spWeb, headers, Body);
                }
            }
        });
```